# debugging on ARM - inspecting the stack

Tags: gdb, arm

I have this particular statement :-

`0x133541a2 <_ZN13AIFFAudioFile14+794>: 9259     str    r2, [sp, #356]`

and my r2 seems to have a value of 0x41414141; how could I evaluate [sp, #356] so that I could look at the value at the resulting address?

I understand the #356 ends up accessing a value from the literal pool, so how can I go about inspecting the resultant address into which r2 is stored?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Its enough to use $sp+356, but something to remember is that 356 is in decimal, not hex. Thats what was confusing me earlier.